# Will scholars get a sin on a disputed topic if they are wrong?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, islamic-scholar

Assalamualaikum, I actually always had this question, if we take a disputed topic like masturbation or any other topic like this where scholars have divided opinion, some says that particular act is haram, some says it's halal and some say it's makrooh, so if that act is haram, will the scholars who says it's halal get a sin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well-known hadith in this regard, that if a judge makes a ruling to the best of his knowledge and ability he will be rewarded, even if he is mistaken. But if he is correct in his ruling, he will have two rewards.

It is important to note that this still assumes the ruling is made in good faith and with the intent to uphold Allah's laws; if someone acts on his own whim and decrees something halal knowing it is haram, or vice-versa, that is a clear sin.

Comment: Here's the hadith for example [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7352) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1716a)